# How to add a google map with a dropdown box to a fragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3

I need to add a Google map to fragment with drop-down like this.

[image]

When user select drop-down app need to locate the position.I tried to use same code that is used for MapsActivity in android studio.I'm getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` this the code I'm using in the fragment

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

public MapFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.googlemap);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(7, 81);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Sri Lanka"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

in .xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="arimac.dss.lk.dsi.fragments.MapFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/googlemap"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="arimac.dss.lk.dsi.MapsActivity" />
```

How can add both dropdown and Google map

Comment: you want to display static map or user can interact with it ?

Comment: I need to mark some cities using dropdown in Google map using Google map api

Comment: provide logs about the error for the community to better understand the issue.